# Pixel 5 emulator in Android-Studio won't allow for multiple images to be selected from the photo gallery at the same time

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-virtual-device

I am on Android Studio Chipmunk (2021.2.1 Patch 2) and using the Pixel 5 emulator.

I have an Android app that allows the user to enter the gallery and select photos - one or many. Using the Pixel 3 emulator everything works like it should. I can grab as many or as few images as I like. Just click to leave a blue check and when done, select done. Also worked fine on the Pixel 3 physical phone I had at the time.

With the Pixel 5 emulator it allows me to select 1 image only. Long click does nothing. Any tips or tricks to get the emulator to allow the user to select in excess of 1 image?

I'm on a MacBook

Answer (score 0):

In lieu of finding a more recent pixel to use I created a new device in device manager that is a "phone" running on API 33. Multiple select worked just fine on this "custom" device. I was able to accomplish the testing of the code on a more recent version of the API, which was my goal. Not sure what is up with the Pixel 5 emulator but there is a workaround.